# How to simultaneously play audio as soon as we get data from esp32 in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, bluetooth

I made a flutter app in which I am receiving audio data from esp32 via bluetooth and temporarily buffering it in an uint8list and then saving it in a .wav file after the entire data has been received but I want to simultaneously play the audio while it is getting recorded. I have tried multiple packages like [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) and [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) to play audio directly from the uint8 array or the byte array but nothing helped.

Can anyone help on how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Sadly this is not a question best suited for SO. SO deals primarily with specific programming based problems. You could help improve the question by including a minimal reproduce-able example. Even then, there are quite a few issues to be covered. I think you would be best pursuing this question elsewhere.

Comment: That said, Bluetooth audio is its own protocol and is built on Bluetooth Classic. The Bluetooth Low Energy module of the ESP32 will likely not allow for the bandwidth required to stream audio. Bluetooth audio has its own set of codecs and simply sending bytes will not yield great results. If you want to continue to pursue your method, you should drop the sample rate and bit depth as low as possible. Even then a continuous stream can’t be guarenteed

Comment: I‘d also prototype this outside of flutter as there are enough unknown variables as it is.